# Is It Safe To Login Once Then Set The JWT On axios?

Tags: reactjs, security, axios, jwt

I login to my ReactJS application using msal/Azure AD which sends me a JWT. I then set it on the headers of axios so all future calls to the REST API have the token until I logout:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common["JWT"] = azureProps.jwtIdToken;
```

Is this safe or am I leaving myself open to attacks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is safe. Usually JWT token has a timeout (10 mins or a few days for example) so it will go expire eventually. If someone somehow gets that token, they will not be able to use it after it expires.